# ECONNREFUSED when dispatch action in nuxtServerInit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am converting my Nuxt application to SSR - because I want to use `nuxtServerInit` and `asyncData`. These are the steps I have taken to convert it.

1. Remove `ssr: false` from `nuxt.config.js`
2. Dispatch actions to initialize store's state in `nuxtServerInit` inside `store/index.js`

---

Now my `nuxt.config.js` looks like this

```js
require("dotenv").config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` });

export default {
  router: {
    base: "/app/",
  },
  target: "static",
  head: {
    // Some head, meta, link config
  },
  css: ["@/assets/scss/main.scss"],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ["@/assets/scss/*.scss", "@/assets/scss/main.scss"],
  },
  plugins: ["@/plugins/apiFactory.js"],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
    ["@nuxtjs/dotenv", { filename: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` }],
  ],
  modules: [
    "bootstrap-vue/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources",
    ["nuxt-sass-resources-loader", "@/assets/scss/main.scss"],
  ],
  build: {
    splitChunks: {
      layouts: true,
    },
  },
};
```

And the `store/index.js` looks like this.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const state = () => ({
  data: [],
});

export const mutations = {
  setData(state, data) {
    state.data = data;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    // Before converting to SSR this action was dispatched in page/component that need this data
    await dispatch("fetchData");
  },
  async fetchData({ commit }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3030/my/api/path");
    commit("setData", data);
  },
};

export const getters = { /* some getters */ };
```

---

But after I restarted the development server - I was greeted with `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3030`

[image: Error]

These are the steps I've taken after that

- Check if the API on `localhost:3030` is running and accessible - It's running and accessible via direct URL and Postman
- Comment out the `// await dispatch("fetchData");` in `nuxtServerInit` - restarted the dev server - site is accessible again but without initial data.

So, I suspected that the action dispatched in `nuxtServerInit` cause the problem - If it is how do I fix this problem or where should I look into next? Please let me know, Thanks!

---

Additional Information

- The API on `localhost:3030` is Lumen version 7.2.2
- The application will be deployed on shared hosting

Comment: Have you found a solution for this in the meantime? I am experiencing the same problem.  Everywhere in the nuxt components the axios API call goes through, only in the index.js store inside nuxtServerInit I get an Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 ... Cheers Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that nuxt can't connect to your host from where it resides.
In my case it is docker container where 127.0.0.1 is... the container! So you have to change baseUrl to actually accessible server from that container.

```
const axiosPlugin: Plugin = ({ $axios, isDev }) => {
    if (isDev && process.server) $axios.setBaseURL('http://172.22.0.1:3000/api')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own server add your api domain in hosts file (in linux /etc/hosts)

```
127.0.0.1 api.domain.com
```

I was struggling for 2 days to understand why it wasn`t working and then it hit me pm2 server side has access only locally.

Answer (score 0):

this happend becuse your axios baseURL port at nuxt.config.js not same with port of command yarn run dev

example right config of axios:-
1-
nuxt.config.js
axios: {
baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
},

then start server command must have --port with same axios port

yarn run dev --port 5000